# Can't access spring-boot rest-endpoint inside docker container when using docker-compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm setting up spring-boot applications inside docker with docker-compose and need to access a rest endpoint from one application on port 8080 from my localhost. The following endpoint works fine when started locally  `http://localhost:8080/central/products`.

I'm on ubuntu 19.10 and running docker version 18.09.5. When I set up a simple spring-boot application for docker like explained on https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/, everything works as expected and I can reach the endpoint on `http://localhost:8080/`. However, when I start more services with docker-compose I'm not able to reach this endpoint from my localhost.

Dockerfile for building the spring-boot application:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","sample.EfridgeCentralApplication"]
```

docker-compose.yml file that seems to cause the problem:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  central-london:
    image: demo/efridge-central:latest
    container_name: central-london
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8080
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=mongo-central
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
      - APP_RABBIT_HOSTNAME=rabbit-efridge

  factory-usa:
    image: demo/efridge-factory:latest
    container_name: factory-usa
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8081
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=usa
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=mongo-usa
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
      - APP_RABBIT_HOSTNAME=rabbit-efridge

  factory-china:
    image: demo/efridge-factory:latest
    container_name: factory-china
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8082
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=china
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=mongo-china
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
      - APP_RABBIT_HOSTNAME=rabbit-efridge

  mongo-central:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo-central
    hostname: mongo-central
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  mongo-usa:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo-usa
    hostname: mongo-usa
    ports:
      - 27018:27017

  mongo-china:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo-china
    hostname: mongo-china
    ports:
      - 27019:27017

  rabbit-efridge:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbit-efridge
    hostname: rabbit-efridge
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
```

Output from docker inspect:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "b91760f810a656e382d702dd408afe3c5ffcdf4c0cd15ea8550150867ac038cc",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Logs from spring-boot

```
2019-07-03 11:54:57.654  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-07-03 11:54:57.803  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-07-03 11:54:57.804  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-07-03 11:54:58.149  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/central]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-07-03 11:54:58.150  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6950 ms
2019-07-03 11:54:59.810  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongo-central:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2019-07-03 11:54:59.810  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server mongo-central:27017 to client view of cluster
2019-07-03 11:55:00.256  INFO 1 --- [o-central:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:11}] to mongo-central:27017
```

The output from `docker inspect` of the working spring-boot container and the not working looks almost the same. I can also access the rabbitmq web interface and MongoDB via mongo client. The only thing that does not work is access to the rest endpoint via `http://localhost:8080/central/products`.

Comment: What's the error? Connection refused, or something else?

Comment: A frequent cause of this class of problem is a service configured to only listen on 127.0.0.1 (look for “listen address” or “bind address” type settings).  To be reachable from other containers it must be bound to 0.0.0.0 (“all interfaces”).

Comment: When I do ```curl -v http://localhost:8080/central/products``` I get ```Recv failure: Connection reset by peer```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `application.properties` file, where I still had  `server.address=localhost` specified.

Removing this line solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

your Dockerfile is lacking the `EXPOSE` statement, therefore no ports are exposed to the outer world.

once you add `EXPOSE 8080` to the bottom of your Dockerfile, your app will be reachable from outside the container.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try it out and let you know. But then I'm wondering why it is working with the example from spring that I provided in my question. There is also no EXPOSE and it works fine.

Comment: the base image allready exposed port 8080. if you have any github repo of your project i would love to take a look

Comment: Sadly this did not solve the issue. I still get the same error

Comment: have any repo??

Comment: It's currently on a private hosted git. I can put it on github later today. Thanks for your help